# The else statement in this .ejs file is showing error "Unexpected token else in /home/ubuntu/workspace/v1/views/home.ejs while compiling ejs"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```html
<% if(!currentUser) %>
<% { %> 
<span><a href="/login"><i class="fab fa-keycdn" style="font-size: 9em ; color:black; margin: 55 0 0 475"></a></i></span>
   <%}%>
   
   <%else{%>                                   
   <span><a href="/dashboard"><i class="fab fa-keycdn" style="font-size: 9em ; color:black; margin: 55 0 0 475"></a></i></span>   
<%}%>
```

This is the code, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The tag before `else` has to be paired with the end tag of the previous. Otherwise the statements will evaluate separately and produce an error.

```
<% if (condition) { %>
  <h1>statement1</h1>
<% } else { %>  
  <h1>statement2</h1>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it in another way place the curly braces as shown below and tag it appropriately.

```
if { 
// if block code statements 

} else {
//else block code statements
}
```

so it becomes

```
<% if { %>
// if block code statements 

<% } else { %>
//else block code statements
<% } %>
```